# How to prove the convexity of the logrithmic gamma function?

Tags: calculus, convex-optimization

Here's what I did:

$$\Gamma'(z)=\int_0^\infty \log(t)e^{-t}t^{z-1}dt$$

$$\Gamma''(z)=\int_0^\infty \log^2(t)e^{-t}t^{z-1}dt$$$$\frac{d^2}{dz^2}\log\Gamma(z)=\frac{\Gamma''(z)\Gamma(z)-(\Gamma'(z))^2}{\Gamma^2(z)}$$

If denote $(e^{-t}t^{z-1})^{1/2}$ as $a$, $(\log^2(t)e^{-t}t^{z-1})^{1/2}$ as $b$, then by cauchy-schwarz inequality, $(\int ab)^2\le(\int a^2)(\int b^2) $, the second derivative of $\log\Gamma$ is greater than zero. Am I right? I checked digamma and polygamma function, but their expressions look weird.

Comment: It seems fine to me (actually, I really liked you're approach). You could also use Holder's inequality to show what you want directly from the definition of convexity

Comment: Be cautious when you differentiate indefinite integrals functions.